# mysql query compare dates, DATEDIFF not working

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to compare the current date to the a column with a date string but no rows are being returned.  `next_reminder` is the name of the column with the date string in the format `2015-09-09`

```
SELECT * FROM my_reminders 
WHERE DATEDIFF(now(),STR_TO_DATE(next_reminder,'%m/%d/%Y')) == 0 
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

How do i solve this?  Row should be returned because today's date is `2015-09-09`

Comment: Is it correct you want the items with next_reminder is today?

Comment: If `next_reminde` already in `Y-m-d` format then why to use `str_to_date()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [curdate()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) to get current datetime and convert that to a date (using the [date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function) like this

```
SELECT * FROM my_reminders 
WHERE date(next_reminder) = curdate()
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

Comment: And my look at it is cleaner and works even if the mysql is using another date format :)